# Externalize Content in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to seperate my content and views (rather anti climactic, I know). What I want is something like gettext where I can have a key in the view. Something like `Content_Materials_Index_Description` and then using something like `echo  "@Content_Materials_Index_Description"` in order to render 3-4 paragraphs of content that I have stored in a seperate file.

I know how to do this in Java/J2EE applications and even VB.net and would like suggestions on doing this using Zend Framework.

Explanation:

view:

```
 <div id="wrapper"> 
  <a href="/Home">HomePage</a>
  <div id="content"><?echo "@content_materials_index_Description"?></div>
 </div>
```

messageResource.ini file

```
content_materials_index_Description=Materials for production can be edited here. Click on the name of a material to edit it. The cross sign...
```

Comment: You're not clear. What exactly is your question. What have you tried? Show some code, how did you fail?

Comment: What's anti climaCtic about seperating content and view?

Comment: What I have found are translators, but it works more like fetching an entire block of text.

Comment: What I want to achieve is: the application resource properties files that are available in J2EE

Comment: Also I am sure @ sign does something in Strings used with Zend Framework. If you use @ in a route in Zend Framework, it throws an error.

Comment: @ is the error supressor and should not be used in 99% of all cases.

Comment: Not sure why [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.using.html) has yet to be mentioned.

Comment: I meant @ in a string. For some reason, using @ in Zend Route causes an error. I know @ supresses error. In Android, @ is used for extracting content from a resource file. I figured Zend might have something like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use partials for that and you can pass some parameters to it to render the content e.g. Table, List, etc.

View file

```
$this->partial('path-to-partial/partial-name.phtml', array(
    'var1'=>$myVar1, 
    'var2' => $myVar2
));
```

Partial file

```
$this->myVar1;
$this->myVar2;
```

Other than that you can use [View helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,

in IndexController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //here you need to read the values from *.ini file. for ex. with Zend_Config_Ini
    $this->view->content_materials_index_Description = 'text for description....';
}
```

in View index.phtml

```
<div><?php echo $this->content_materials_index_Description; ?></div>
```